# How can I get the Xcode6 editor to highlight the lines I have changed from my last commit?

Tags: xcode

I am looking for functionality similar to what I get with sublime text (with the git-gutter plugin), such as the image below. In the gutter I can see I deleted some lines(red) and changed some lines (yellow).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently found the [GitDiff](https://github.com/johnno1962/GitDiff) plugin for xcode, which does pretty much what I want.

Xcode plugins can be installed and removed using [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/)